# Python argument counting

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I just got into arguments in Python and I find it strange the way the arguments system works in Python (I'm not sure about other languages). For example:

```
from sys import argv

arg1, arg2, arg3 = argv

print "First argument: ", arg1
print "Second argument: ", arg2
print "Third argument: ", arg3
```

When I run this in command line with the arguments that follow:

```
python example.py First Second
```

It gives the output:

```
First argument: example.py
Second argument: First
Third argument: Second
```

Does this mean that python starts counting from zero? Or is there some different or some more reasons it does that. It's odd, but interesting.

Comment: @GregHewgill Point duly noted and edited below.

Comment: On a side note, I'd use argparse which is a much better way to read command-line arguments and also provide options for help. This is the defacto option used by some of the popular python libs.

Comment: @Joseph I think you are reading **Learn Python The Hard Way**, am I correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Python uses zero-based indexing as you surmised (and as many other programming languages also do).

`sys.argv` is a list of strings.

`sys.argv[0]` will contain the name of the script, and subsequent entries in this list of strings will contain command line arguments provided to the script.

I was going to provide an example, but what you have in your post is as good as I could come up with.

Finally, as @GregHewgill points out in a helpful comment below, the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) provide more information on this as well.

Comment: Python's documentation is great, too. It's documented here: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

Comment: @GregHewgill I'll add a link to this in my answer if you are ok with it?

Answer (score 4):

Arguments have counted from 0 since C with `argv`, and possibly before then. Argument 0 is the executable/script name, and all the other arguments following it start at 1.